# Как использовать класс в котором храниться текст. Для 3 языков?

Tags: java, android, android-resources

Как использовать Класс в котором храниться текст. Для 3 языков? Android

Есть класс

```
public final class Astro{
    String A="asdads";
    String B="CCACA";
}
```

Мне надо весь текст из этого класса добавить в ресурсы, а тут лишь оставить ссылки на ресурсы, чтобы при смене языка текст поменялся на нужны мне.

`getResource` использовать не могу, потому что данный класс статический и у него нет `Context`.

---

```
public final class Constants {
    public static final String REGISTER_PAY_SUM = "pay sum";
    public static final String CATEGORY_RESPONSE = "category response";
    public static final String COURSE_ID = "courseId";
    public static final String SUBCATEGORY_ID = "subcategory id";
    public static final String JSON_FILE_NAME = "json file name";
    public static final String SUBCATEGORY_NAME = "subcategory name";
    public static final String CHAPTER = "chapter";
    public static final String LESSON_ID = "lesson id";
    public static final String QUIZ_ITEM = "quizItem";
    public static final String QUIZ_COUNT = "quizCount";
    public static final String SEARCH_QUERY = "search query";
    public static final String NUM_OF_QUESTION = "numOfQuestion";
    public static final String ANSWER_ID = "numOfAnswer";
    public static final String USER_TOKEN = "userToken";
    }
```

---

```
    public class BaseApp extends Application {
    public static Context context;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        context=getApplicationContext();
    }
}
```

Comment: А почему бы, собственно не использовать id ресурсов (R.string.blabla) - они сами по себе константы, от языка не зависят,  контекста не требуют и у switсh с интами никаких проблем. А доставать строку из ресурсов только там, где реально нужен текст - контекст там есть наверняка (любой view его хранит).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `getResource` использовать не могу, потому что данный класс статический и у него нет `Context`.

Предложу два варианта:

1. Вы всегда можете получить `ApplicationContext` и вызвать от него метод `getResources()`:

   ```
   public class App extends Application {
       private static Context sContext;

       @Override
       public void onCreate() {
           super.onCreate();
           sContext = this;
       }

       public static Context getInstance() {
           return sContext;
       }
   }
   ```

   И далее где-нибудь:

   ```
   public static void foo() {
       Resources resources = App.getInstance().getResources();
       // ...
   }
   ```

   Вообще, [Google не рекомендует расширять класс `Application`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html) (**если на это нет веских оснований**).
2. (*этот способ в общем случае плохой, но если все делать аккуратно, то можно и так*). Передайте в статический метод `Context`, но будьте аккуратны, **передача ссылки на активити чревата утечками памяти**.

Comment: 1) "Google не рекомендует расширять класс Application" -  да ладно, с таким же успехом можно не рекомендовать расширять класс Activity, какие еще основания нужны 3) Существует еще третий способ - через рефлексию и ничего расширять и передавать не надо, но это совсем "фу", в первую очередь потому, что версии андроид надо все время мониторить, смотреть не перестало ли работать и обновлять.

Comment: @Rou1997, Да [серьезно](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html). И это, прочитайте, пожалуйста, то, что написано в скобках.

Comment: @post_zeew, Это единственное решение? Ну если другого способа нет значит надо создать статический Context в APP. И почему будет утечка то?

Comment: @post_zeew И где тут "не рекомендуется"? Написано "normally no need" - это значит, что для формата APK необязательно это делать, что нет такого, как с точкой входа main() в executables. А что нельзя - это не значит.

Comment: @xTIGRx, Думаю, не единственное. Можно придумать еще много всяких извращений (и не очень извращений). Наследование `Application` не чревато утечками памяти, а вот передача ссылки на `Activity` куда-либо – вполне чревато. Вот передадите, сохраните, активити уничтожится, а ссылка на нее будет висеть.

Comment: @post_zeew Кстати, по поводу уничтожаемых активити - так передавайте не Activity, а тот,что возвращает getApplicationContext() - тогда не должно быть такой проблемы.

Comment: @Rou1997, Может быть и так, но в контексте той фразы я понимаю те слова как `не расширяйте... так как требуемый функционал можно получить другими способами`.

Comment: @Rou1997, Да, можно и так, но только в том случае, если есть возможность вызова `getApplicationContext()`.

Comment: @post_zeew, Ваш способ не подходит мне. У меня из за этого во всем коде тебе Константы не валидны.

`Switch ругается на них Constant expression required`

Comment: @xTIGRx, Скорее всего Вы что-то делаете не так. Данный способ не затрагивает Ваш код.

Comment: @post_zeew,

`public static final String LOGIN_FRAGMENT_TAG = BaseApp.context.getString(R.string.const_login);`.

Выше обновил BaseApp

Comment: @post_zeew, Из за `public static final String LOGIN_FRAGMENT_TAG = BaseApp.context.getString(R.string.const_login);` У меня теперь это не константы, а переменные. А Switch принимает только константы.

И чо щяс делать?

Comment: @post_zeew, Раньше case работал так как он принимал `public static final String LOGIN_FRAGMENT_TAG="Text"` . А теперь ругается

Comment: @xTIGRx, Ну да, в `case` значения должны быть определены на момент компиляции. На вскидку ничего, кроме `if-else` не скажу, но это плохо. Попробуйте как-то перестроить логику.

Answer (score 0):

Предлагаю не делать велосипедов, а использовать стандартный механизм поддержки нескольких языков. Почитать можно [тут](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/locale.php)

Т.е. тебе нужно будет создать несколько файлов strings.xml  под каждый язык, и из кода обращаться по ID строкового ресурса и уже сам android тебе вернет строку на нужном языке

Если хочешь изменять язык во время исполнения программы, то читать [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12230553/android-how-to-change-the-application-language-at-runtime)

Comment: Вы явно не внимательно прочитали что мне нужно.

Обновил вопрос выше. Вы видите константы? Так вот вместо текста там должны быть ссылки на strings. Чтобы когда я изменил strings.xml или strings-ar.xml то автоматически Android подхвачивал и подставлял нужны текст по языку.

`щяс у меня вопрос такой. Как мне сделать чтобы вместо текста там были ссылки типо getString`

Comment: А там где вы будете использовать этот класс есть доступ к контексту?